# Protect a SignalR hub shared between many sites

Tags: authentication, .net-core, signalr, identityserver4, access-token

I need to protect a SignalR hub shared between many sites.

At this moment this is obtained using a JWT Token that clearly identify the user logged to the site opening a connection with the SignalR hub.

The problem is that the token is genereted from an IdentityServer4 during login is keeped only on server side (authentication in all sites is implemented using cookie ) and we dont'want to keep the token in the user browser.

The token must contains the user subject in order to store the relation of all the SignalR connection to each user, thus we cannot use a temporary token (machine to machine) to protect the SignalR resource.

Any suggestion on how to keep the user access token safe, and meanwhile guaranteed a protected access to the SignalR hub?